How can I create a table inside Trino docker container using a parquet file?
I am trying to use the Trino image locally to use as a base for testing dbt commands; my intention is to use a parquet file to create a dummy table inside the container. However, I cannot find the syntax I need to create the table. This is how I am trying to mount the raw file into the container:
docker run -p 8080:8080 trinodb/trino      
docker cp test_parq.parquet [IMAGE_ID]:/test_parq.parquet
docker exec -it [IMAGE_ID] trino 

then here I am trying to create the table from the file (2 separate attempts):
CREATE TABLE memory.tst  AS (SELECT * FROM "test_parq");

CREATE TABLE tst WITH (external_location = 'test_parq', format='PARQUET') AS SELECT * FROM 'test_parq';

using the memory schema arbitrarily as it should be mutable.
